# Blank alert confirmation box from javascript function, when called from HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm currently programming a website system as part of my studies. I'm using PHP,HTML and Javascript throughout the project. I'm a novice programmer and i'm learning as i go along.

My current problem is that when a form submit button is pressed e.g. UPDATE or DELETE. I wanted a confirmation box asking the user 'Are you sure you want to submit?' using javascript. However whenever I click the button , an empty alert box appears even though there is text inside the JS function. Please look at the code below ! :

```
function confirm()
{
    return alert("Are you want to submit the form"?);
}
</script>
```

The html code is echoed in a php while loop

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update  value=update onclick='confirm();'" . "> </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete  value=delete onclick='confirm();'" . "> </td>";
```

I am grateful for anyone taking their time to help !

Comment: Might be because `confirm` is a reserverd word in JavaScript and is used to display a confirmation box.

Comment: you have an error in your javascript. the ? is outside the quotes

Comment: ok, i will change the function name and see if that solves the problem!

Comment: `<script>function confirm()
{
    return alert("Are you want to submit the form?");
}
</script>` - in case you missed the `<script>` tag. Plus, the "?" was outside your quotes. Code worked fine for me.

Comment: @putvande Seems like answers below have probably been feeding off your comment. My comment/code above worked fine; displaying a pop up dialog.

Comment: Hehe.. I guess so. Wonder why it initially didn't work for me. Never mind.. it works indeed.

Comment: and @Fred-ii-  !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved guys! appreciate all your help, was an error in with the ? in the javascript function. Funnily enough, it wasn't using confirm as my function name! won't use confirm next time for good practice.

```
return alert("Are you want to submit the form"?); <- ? outside of ""
```

Corrected

```
return alert("Are you want to submit the form?");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(confirm("question")){
// yes
} else {
//no
}
```

confirm() is a javascript reserved word

Comment: Its actually not a reserved word I think, but just a function that can't be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

`confirm()` is already a Javascript function.  The question mark should also remain inside the double-quotes.  Change your function name for clarity:

```
function confirmForm()
{
    return alert("Are you want to submit the form?");
}

echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update  value=update onclick='confirmForm();'" . "> </td>";
```